# how can I make a string object's value in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
{x : 425, y:25}
```

I have a string like "425,25"
I need output like

```js
{x: 425, y:25}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Simple split, convert to number, and assignment

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` and `.map()` functions. Consider the steps mentioned below:

- Split the input string using `.split()` function by passing comma `,` as delimiter.
- Map the returned array by passing `Number` function that will convert strings to corresponding numeric values.
- Use array destructuring to unpack values from returned array in desired variables.
- Use object literal notation to create an object with these variables.

```js
let data = "425,25",
    [x, y] = data.split(",").map(Number),
    result = {x, y};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about that? with **ES6 Rename Object Keys in Javascript**

```js
//{x: 425, y:25}
const arr = "425,25".split(',').map(Number); //maps value to Number after split
const {0: x,1: y} = {...arr}; // make array to object and rename keys i.e x,y
const result = {x,y} // wrap variable to object
console.log(result); // your expected result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string using the string's [.split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). This will give you an array with the two strings `'425'` and `'25'`. You can then parse them into integers using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), and create an object with them:

```js
const input = '425,25';
const substrings = input.split(',');

const result = {
  x: parseInt(substrings[0], 10),
  y: parseInt(substrings[1], 10),
};

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Don't forget to `parseInt` them with base 10